# Add "Refresh" menu item or button

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

I hope I'm not missing out on something because I find the only way to refresh a question or its answers in the app is to scroll all the way to the top then pull down to refresh.

The refresh button that I sometimes see on the toolbar doesn't consistently appear there. Sometimes it is replaced by Ask a Question button or something else. When viewing questions it is never there.

I hope a persistent "Refresh" menu item can be added to the menu which shows up when the menu button is tapped. This will help avoid having to scroll all the way to the top and then pull down just to refresh, as I can then refresh any time I want regardless of where I am on the scroll.

A persistent "Ask a Question" could also be added to the menu, so that I don't have to play chance with the indeterminate toolbar to get to the function.

Comment: I may not want to move back to the top of the page just to refresh, even if I can do it automatically. I may be reading comments below a post, or reading an actively ongoing discussion in some answer in the middle. If I have to go to the top just to refresh, then I have to find scroll down and find where I left off! All the other apps have an option to refresh without having to pull. **Why is this status-declined?**

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @ADTC `I may be reading comments below a post, or reading an actively ongoing discussion in some answer in the middle.`

If you do this and refresh, your state will be lost anyway so it's kind of a moot point. We're in the process of adding real-time updates to the views, this should help your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Our action bar is currently static, meaning it doesn't change from view to view. This might be changed later down the line, but for now there's an easy way to refresh questions that you haven't stumbled upon yet: Tap on the header for Question, or Answer, and it'll immediately move you back to the top of the page. From there you can simply pull to refresh and done!

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me about it, but still I may not want to move back to the top of the page just to refresh, even if I can do it automatically. *Please see comment on question.*